# Power Button VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to replace the Z key with the PC Power key, I already disabled it in the control panel, if pressed does nothing, I wanted to use it by the VB program.

Someone to give a little help?

I've done a lot of research and nothing is complicated because it is a special key.

Thank you

```
Private Function LowLevelKeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer

    If nCode = HC_ACTION Then
    If wParam = WM_KEYDOWN Then
    Dim key As Integer = lParam.vkCode
    If key = Keys.Z Then
    Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t 0")
    End If
```

Comment: When you say "power button", do you mean the actual power button on the computer or the Sleep key on the keyboard? If the former, that's not possible using your current method as it isn't part the keyboard. If the latter, use `Keys.Sleep`.

Comment: yes it's the pc button, not the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/s")
```

Comment: this part works well, I wanted to replace the z key with the power button.